# Meaning of # symbol as argument in strcmp()

Tags: c++, c, macros, strcmp

I came across this line of code in legacy code:

```
#define func(x,y)  if(strcmp(x,#y)==0)
```

Anyone have an idea of the purpose for the `#` symbol preceding `y`?

Comment: Is that in a macro? If it is, it's the [Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) operator.

Comment: That code will not compile? where did you extract the example from? can you post the complete code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as mentioned in the comments, this seems like [stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) in a c macro.

here is a little example that uses your sample code:

```
#define doif(x, y) \
    if(strcmp(x,#y)==0) { \
        printf("doing! %s\n",x); \
    }\
    else { \
        printf("not doing!\n"); \
    } 

int main()
{
    char x[] = "test";

    doif (x, test);
    doif (x, something);

    return 0;
}
```

the stringification operator actually pastes `y` variable as a string before the compilation stage

Comment: This is link only answer. Give concrete example to illustrate your point.

Comment: @PranitKothari, you are right, here is a little example containing the OP's code snippet

Answer (score 1):

First of all you posted wrong or in complete code. `#y` should be used with macro definition, not while using macro.

```
#define MAC(STR) #STR    

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    printf(MAC(ME));//prints ME
    printf(MAC("ME"));//prints "ME"

    return 0;
}
```

Here I have defined MAC macro which takes one argument. I did it's stringification.

Also see second printf, it exactly prints string. So you need not to give pair of `""`.

Comment: Why is this named `CONCAT`? There's no concatenation here. The preprocessor does also have a concatenation operator, by the way.

Comment: Yes I know it's `##`, it's just name of macro. But confusing, so changing it.